# Show actions with Ionic push notifications

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ionic2

I am trying to implement notification Actions using Ionic [custom push notifications](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push#section-customizing-your-notification-appearance) and the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#action-buttons).

Unfortunately, even if message and title work perfectly, I didn't have any luck showing the actions buttons yet.

This is my cURL request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"tokens": ["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"],
"profile": "push01",
"notification": {
    "message": "test",
    "android": {
      "title": "test android",
      "data": {
        "actions": [
          { "icon": "emailGuests", "title": "EMAIL GUESTS", "callback": "app.emailGuests", "foreground": true},
          { "icon": "snooze", "title": "SNOOZE", "callback": "app.snooze", "foreground": false }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this with Ionic 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was some sort of incompatibility issues with some of the SDK library versions.

See this as reference: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/767

Answer (score 1):

The callback function "app.emailGuests" needs to be accessible from the global scope.

Something like this:

```
window.app = {};
window.app.emailGuests = function(data){
    // Do stuff when button is clicked
    console.log('Notification data: ', data);
};
```

Comment: Can you please guide how to handle it in Ionic 2?